# download Spotify music converter?

Tags: software-installation

I just wonder if TuneFab Spotify Music Converter can be accessed on ubuntu? I heard that it can convert spotify songs to MP3, that is what I want. Because spotify songs can't be played on my MP3 player.

Comment: That software is for Mac only. And whether or not it's legal to remove DRM is a grey area in some jurisdictions and clearly illegal in most. Considering that and the fact this has nothing to do with Ubuntu this question should be closed.

Comment: Might also consider Spotify is being sued for copyright infringement. https://www.theverge.com/2018/1/2/16842402/spotify-wixen-music-publishing-lawsuit-publishers-songwriters

Answer (score 11):

I wrote a converter myself, for a specific use case, but it can be used for general purposes as well. See : [here](https://snippets.geertvandeweyer.be/index.php?page=read&id=45) . It can download to either mp3 or flac and adds metadata. Again : check if what you are doing is legal before using it.

Download it as:

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/geertvandeweyer/spotify_recorder
```

It depends on the QT libraries and pulse-audio, recording the spotify signal in realtime. After the playlist finishes, songs are splitted and metadata is provided in ID3 tags.

Simply copy the URI from spotify of an album or playlist, and run the following command:

```
perl stream_recorder.pl --uri 'spotify:album:3BS9MUmVKghsOa7Y3otqpE' --silent --format flac --outdir /home/user/Music/
```

Some of the options are :

- uri : the album/playlist identififier. Copy it from the three dots & share in the spotify client
- silent : a boolean to mute spotify while recording
- format : flac or mp3 (vbr high quality)
- outdir : target location of the recorded songs

Comment: @DavidFoerster: ok, my bad. I extended the answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can the stream recorder store the audio sample data as it is (in some standard container format)? I presume that Spotify uses some well known lossy audio compression protocol. It would be a shame to either lose quality by transcoding to a (different) lossy format or space by transcoding to a lossless format.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I know that spotify uses OGG internally, but the tool picks up the pulse-audio stream, at which point it is already decoded I guess.

Comment: Ok, so it's just a generic PulseAudio sink-input recorder. Understood!

Comment: It says the command 'hg' is not found. Should I install mercurial?

Comment: It says the command 'hg' is not found. Should I install mercurial?

Comment: the repo is inaccessible since bitbucket shut down mercurial support.

Answer (score 3):

TuneFab Spotify Music Converter is only available for Mac, in case you want to do the same in Ubuntu, you have to search for a software alternative available in this OS, like Spotify Ripper, spotify-dl, Spotify Downloader.

In the following links you can download those tools:

- [Spotify Ripper](https://github.com/hbashton/spotify-ripper).
- [spotify-dl](https://github.com/invicnaper/spotify-dl)
- [Spotify Downloader](https://github.com/ritiek/spotify-downloader)

But it is also important to consider the comment from @MichaelBay: "And whether or not it's legal to remove DRM is a grey area in some jurisdictions and clearly illegal in most. Considering that and the fact this has nothing to do with Ubuntu this question should be closed".

Having that clear, you're free to decide, hope it helps and good luck.

Comment: Regardless of criminality this is at least a breach of the contract with Spotify.